# How to clean up TeamCity's remote-run branches from repository?

Tags: git, build, teamcity

TeamCity allows one [to run personal builds from branches](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD65/Branch+Remote+Run+Trigger). So in order to trigger a build I need to run something like `git push origin feature-branch:remote-run/feature-branch`. But how this branch would be removed later?

I do not need it after I got build results. It is fairly possible that I will edit (rebase, squash etc) branch before pushing it to main repository and thus this ref will be garbage. I think it would be convenient to remove branch at the end of each remote-run build. Is this branch name accessible via some build property or something alike so I can delete it automatically? Or maybe I missed something important?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment TeamCity doesn't provide remote-run branch name as a variable, please vote for [this issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/TW-18386). You can delete a branch manually using command `git push origin +:remote-run/feature-branch`.

Comment: The answer I need, but not the answer I wanted.